# How do i loop an nsobject once saved to

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using an `NSMutableArray` to store items in a list form from a web service. How do I read the data out of my array to display a random quote.

As i am trying to avoid hitting the webservice twice or am i over complicating it?

```
NSInteger randomInt = arc4random_uniform(3);
NSString *baseUrl = @"http://movie-quotes.herokuapp.com/api/v1/quotes";
NSString *webServiceUrl= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%ld", baseUrl,(long)randomInt];
randomQuotes = nil;

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    // Load the JSON string from our web serivce (in a background thread)
    NSDictionary * dictionary = [JSONHelper loadJSONDataFromURL:webServiceUrl];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        randomQuotes = [NSMutableArray array];

        // Iterate through the array of quotes records in the dictionary
        for (NSDictionary * oneQuote in dictionary)
        {
            Quotes* newQuotes =[[Quotes alloc] init];

            // Add our new Customer record to our NSMutableArray
            newQuotes.Quote = [oneQuote objectForKey:@"content"];
            newQuotes.FilmName = [oneQuote objectForKey:@"film"];
            [randomQuotes addObject:newQuotes];
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the web service to return a random quote, or are you trying to show a random quote out of the selection returned by the web service?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a random object out of an array like this.

```
NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random_uniform(theArray.count);
[theArray objectAtIndex: randomIndex];
```

As long as you keep the array of quotes around, you won't need to hit the web service again.